# Given a circle γ(t) = (cos t, sin t, 0);Is γ an asymptotic curve of the unit sphere with centre in (0, 0, 0)?

Tags: differential-geometry

I know that the dot product of γ// and N gives the normal curvature andig its 0, then it's called an asymptotic curve.
The equation of the given sphere is x^2 +y^2 + z^2=1---as its an unit sphere with centre at (0,0,0) 
But my problem is, here ow can I find out N?i.e.,the unit normal vector on this sphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x,y,z)$ is a point on the sphere, then the normal there is also $(x,y,z)$.

In general, if a surface is given as a level set $F(x,y,z) = 0$, then the normal to the surface is the gradient $\nabla F$.

Comment: So you are saying the Normal will be (2x,2y,2z) right?

Comment: $\frac{(2x, 2y, 2z)}{|(2x,2y,2z)|}=(x,y,z)$

Comment: @anindita Yeah, as Xipan Xiao points out, I should say the *unit* normal will be $\nabla F / \left|\nabla F\right|$.